# Why statusbar was forcibly missing only iOS8 when device was landscape?

Tags: ios8, statusbar

Please give me advise how to show statusbar when device is landscape.
Of course, I already tried below,

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

To display status bar in landscape mode in ios 8, try following method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```